# Where do you define the django forms?

Tags: django-forms

Probably some simple question, but does it say in Django's homepage where you should define the forms? Does the code goes into the `model.py`? But that file should only consist of Django's database models right? So I wonder where should the forms go into?

Forms that I mean is this one you import

`from django import forms`

and then create for example a form like this (code is taken from Django's homepage)

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject   = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message   = forms.CharField()
    sender    = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where you store your form classes. Django isn't specifically looking for them the way it does for models in your models.py

I usually store them in a forms.py module. Then you import from your forms module in your views.py

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but the module defining the form has to be in the Python search path.

Comment: @Guandalino - I think thats safely assumed if he is creating it in his django project. If its in the root project its in the path. If its in an app then its in the path because of adding the app to the installed apps list.